# How to iterate each variable from a dataframe a reference to it dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-science, outliers

It is possible to reference a dataframe column if you know its name (for example: `dataframe1.time`). I want to iterate each variable from a dataframe and call it like: 'for each x, dataframe1.x'

```
numeric_vars = ['CO_Mean','CO_Min','CO_Max','CO_Std','NO2_Mean', 'NO2_Min', 'NO2_Max','NO2_Std', 'O3_Mean','O3_Min'
                              ,'O3_Max', 'O3_Std', 'PM2.5_Mean', 'PM2.5_Min', 'PM2.5_Max', 'PM2.5_Std', 'PM10_Mean',
                              'PM10_Min', 'PM10_Max', 'PM10_Std', 'SO2_Mean', 'SO2_Min', 'SO2_Max', 'SO2_Std']
for num_var in new_dataset_2[numeric_vars]:
    mean, std = np.mean(new_dataset_2[var]), np.std(new_dataset_2[var])
    cut_off = std * 3
    lower, upper = mean - cut_off, mean + cut_off
    #outliers = [new_dataset_2.index[new_dataset_2[var] == x].tolist() for x in new_dataset_2[var] if x < lower or x > upper]
    new_dataset_2 = new_dataset_2[(new_dataset_2.num_var > lower) & (new_dataset_2.num_var < upper)]
    #for outlier in outliers:
     #   new_dataset_2.drop(outlier)
```

The line new_dataset2.num_var does not work. Is there a way to iterate each column and reference it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

**Short anwser:**
You can replace `new_dataset2.num_var` by `new_dataset2[num_var]`

The notation with [] is equivalent but supports passing a variable.

**Longer anwser:**
When using pandas, the first reflex should be to try to avoid looping over columns (or rows, which is worse) and use pandas build-in function.
For your example, you can probably use the apply() function to apply the same function to all columns.[Pandas apply() doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Since you seem to want to apply it only to numeric columns, you can do a filter in the function you have in your apply with an if.